# Multiple Image only gets height of first div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 images and each of them have a div after it. I am trying to adjust all the image's height to be the same as the height of the div after it.

However, all the images are being given the height of the **first** div, not the one after it.

I believe this is because when `$(".text").outerHeight()` is used, it always gets the height of the first `<div class="text">`. I have tried using this `.each` function to resolve this, but to no avail:

```
$('.container').each(function(i, obj) {
   $(".container").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());
});
```

Here is my full code without the `.each` function:

```js
$(".container").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, .</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want to loop through all `.containers` and target `.text` and the `img` that way, or loop through all `img`'s or `.text`'s and affect the other element.

I'm looping through `.text` here and updating the `img` that comes before it.

```js
$('.text').each(function() {
  $(this).prev('img').css('height',$(this).outerHeight());
})
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, .</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it would have been handy if I had known about the `.prev` function - I never thought of doing it this way. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheCodesee np. you can also use `$.next()` in the opposite direction

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track - the issue is indeed with the specificity of your `.text` selector. You want to scope it so you're using only the `.text` adjacent to the image, not just the first `.text` on the page.

```js
$('.container').each(function(index, element) {

  var $this = $(element),
    $img = $this.find('img'),
    $text = $this.find('.text')[0];
  // we use [0] because $.find returns a collection of elements
  // even if there's only one .text in the .container,
  // and we can't get clientHeight from a collection.
  // it's fine to leave $img as is because $.css
  // works with collections _or_ single elements.

  // then it's as simple as...
  $img.css('height', $text.clientHeight);
});
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  /* this line clears your floats;
     they'll run into each other without it.
     or you can use a clearfix - google for examples. */
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, .</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyNzQyNTcwNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDAwOTQ4Nzk@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="White House Down" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>White House Down (2013)</h2>
    <p>While on a tour of the White House with his young daughter, a Capitol policeman springs into action to save his child and protect the president from a heavily armed group of paramilitary invaders.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```